# @SecondaryTable with where condition

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am creating entity for table created outside of my system. I want to bind data from other table to entity field by using `@SecondaryTable` (or possibly better solution), but only to do so if condition is met. IE. my table has 1 row, I want to bind data from other table (oneToMany) where certain condition is met (exactly one match from other table(transform to one to one)). Can I use `@Where` annotation and how? If not is there alternative?

Edit: here is the entity and additional info on the related table

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "RE_STORAGE_INSTANCE")
public class Movie {

    @Id
    @Column(name="ID_")
    private Long id;

    ...
    //Column I want to fetch
    private Date dueDate;
}
```

Table `RE_VARIABLES` manyToOne to table `RE_STORAGE_INSTANCE`, contains fields: `re_key`, `re_value`. I want to fetch `re_value` only if 're_key' equals dueDate. Even though it's `manyToOne`, only one row of `RE_VARIABLES` contains due date for each `RE_STORAGE_INSTANCE` row.

Comment: Can you update the question with your entity?

Comment: @Alex and could you please also add the related part of your database sсhema.

Comment: @SternK updated the question

Comment: @Alex Does column `dueDate` belong to `RE_STORAGE_INSTANCE` or `RE_VARIABLES`?

Comment: @SternK it is a field of the RE_VARIABLES table

Comment: @Alex Does the `RE_VARIABLES` table have a foreign key to the `RE_STORAGE_INSTANCE` table?

Comment: @SternK not exactly, they are not directly related though they I could use manyToOne to link them, they both have same fk toward 3rd table. I know I could achieve this using full entities, but I'd rather avoid that

Comment: @Alex You can try to use [@Formula](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-column-formula). But if you need this column only for some particular use cases I would suggest you to write a separate query to avoid performance impact.

Comment: @SternK Formula on field level? I believe formula will perform for each row in other table

Comment: @Alex It will perform additional sub select for each row from `RE_STORAGE_INSTANCE`.